# Naming a FlinkKafkaConsumer or Producer

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The DataStreamSink class has a name field. Why does the FlinkKafkaConsumer and FlinkKafkaProducer not have a similar field? In the Flink Dashboard my sinks all say "Unnamed"

Comment: Similarly I am not sure how to name a SourceFunction, it says Custom Source in Dashboard...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to name the sink that is doing the producing, remember the Producer is just the function that does the actions of the sink, but it's still a `DataStreamSink`.

So you just need to do

```
foo.addSink(yourProducer).name("Kafka: " + topic)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are options in Flink StreamExecution Environment to add source name along with any source function. Refer to the java doc link.

env.add(sourceFunction,"Kafka topic");

[Flink Stream Execution environment add source with name](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.html#addSource-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction-java.lang.String-)